# Add missing timestamp in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, timestamp, missing-data

I am struggling to add missing timestamp to a dataframe.

My current output is :

```
    start_Local_round           end_Local_round         alarmId
2020-09-01 00:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 00:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:20:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:30:00+00:00   155698
```

And I need something like :

```
    start_Local_round           end_Local_round         alarmId
2020-09-01 00:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 00:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 00:40:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 00:40:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 00:50:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 00:50:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:00:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:00:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:10:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:10:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:20:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:20:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:40:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:40:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   15568
2020-09-01 01:50:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:00:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560        
2020-09-01 02:10:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:20:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:30:00+00:00   155698
2020-09-01 02:20:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:30:00+00:00   155698
2020-09-01 02:30:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:40:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2020-09-01 02:50:00+00:00   2560
2020-09-01 03:00:00+00:00
2020-09-01 03:10:00+00:00
2020-09-01 03:20:00+00:00
```

The aim is to merge it with an another dataframe which have a timestamp with 10 minutes data as well

I tired to create a dataframe with all the datapoints of the period

```
#création des points 10'
def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta

min_date = df.start_Local.min().round('10min')
max_date = df.start_Local.max().round('10min')
        
dts = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for dt in datetime_range(min_date, max_date, timedelta(minutes=10))]
```

But i can't merge it with my original data.

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can append the second dataframe to the first one (pandas.DataFrame.append) and then order the rows by start time

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))

df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

df.append(df2)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

Comment: I tried `append = dts.append(df)` but it gives me an empty dataframe with NaT for start_Local_round and NaN for alarmId

Comment: It should work if both are dataframes and have the same columns. Is dts a dataframe as you defined it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell you everything I did. I used the code below to create dts then `dts = pd.DataFrame(dts, columns=['start_Local_round'])`  + `dts =pd.to_datetime(dts['start_Local_round'], utc=True)` + `dts = dts.sort_values('start_Local_round')` + `df = df.sort_values('start_Local_round')` + `append = dts.append(df)` . So both are dataframes with the same column and sorted by it

Comment: Can you create dts as a dataframe or not? Is that the problem, or the merging of both dataframes?

Comment: You have to sort the values after merging both dataframes

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Actually I don't have the format with columns A & B for both data frames. One has several columns including the date and the other one only one column with the date. + I have few lines with the same timestamp and I am trying to fill the missing timestamp. So, append doesn't work.

Comment: Well, why don't you then edit the post and describe your dataframes better?

Comment: You should have a closer a look at the one dataframe described

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the answer is :

```
new_df = df.set_index('Start').resample("10min").first().reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```